# Spring JPA Pagination with only boolean check on field

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity called `Skill` which has `is_deleted` boolean value default to `false`.

```
@Repository
public interface SkillRepository extends JpaRepository<Skill, Long> {
    Page<Skill> findAllByOrderByDisplayOrderAsc(Pageable pageable);
}
```

I want to filter out skills that has `is_deleted` true with pagination. How to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Note: You don't need a `@Repository` annotation on your repositories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the property looks like this:

```java
boolean deleted

public boolean isDeleted(){
    return deleted;
}

public void setDeleted(boolean deleted) {
    this.deleted = deleted;
}
```

The following should work.

```java
public interface SkillRepository extends JpaRepository<Skill, Long> {
    Page<Skill> findAllByDeletedIsFalseOrderByDisplayOrderAsc(Pageable pageable);
}
```

If your property is actually named `is_deleted` and not just the column things might get tricky, and I highly recommend to switch to standard Java naming conventions.

You can find a list of possible predicates here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#appendix.query.method.predicate

Comment: The property is `isDeleted` and column is `is_deleted`.

Comment: How to specify this in the method name?

Comment: If the property name is actually `isDeleted` the method name should be  `findAllByIsDeletedIsFalseOrderByDisplayOrderAsc`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `@Column` annotation in your model class to map a field to the `is_deleted` column and use that field in your repository method.

Add something like this in your Skill class (model)

```
...
@Column(name = "is_deleted")
boolean deleted;
...
```

and then you can use the field to search for in the repository like below:

```
Page<Skill> findByDeleted(boolean isDeleted, Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: But I want to order by displayOrder asc.

Comment: I found that providing native query with pagable works. But I would like to know if this can be done without specifying the sql query.

Comment: Just create a method `Page<Skill> findByDeletedOrderByDisplayOrderAsc(boolean isDeleted, Pageable pageable`